# Is it possible to detect position at which backspace is pressed on html input?

Tags: javascript, html, input

```
ref.current.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
   ...
```

I am able to detect backspace using e.code === 'Backspace' but I want to know at which character position its pressed. for example, the input is 123 and the cursor is behind 3 (backspace is pressed to delete 3). or cursor is in front of 1 so backspace is pressed to delete nothing. thanks

Comment: So you have an <input> element?

Comment: @user202729 yes